# Acumatica - Event When File is Attached to Document

Tags: c#, acumatica

I'm looking to run a method when a file is attached to a document in Acumatica (POOrder in this case).  Essentially an event that is fired when a file is attached.

Through my research I was not able to find any documentation or similar questions that relate so I am unable to provide any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File upload within the Acumatica system is done through the `UploadFileMaintenance` graph. The data record that is referenced is `UploadFile`

You can accomplish your goal of "run a method when a file is attached to a document in Acumatica" a variety of ways.

You can add an event handler to UploadFileMaintenance via an extension as seen below

```
public class UploadFileMaintenanceExtension : PXGraphExtension<UploadFileMaintenance>
{
    public virtual void __(Events.RowInserting<UploadFile> e)
    {
    }

    public virtual void __(Events.RowInserted<UploadFile> e)
    {
    }
}
```

Actions can then be determined based on the files origination information ect.

[image: Inserting Information]

Similarly you can add an event for file saving specific to PO with the following

```
public class POOrderEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<POOrderEntry>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<UploadFileMaintenance>((graph) =>
        graph.RowInserting.AddHandler<UploadFile>((sender, e) =>
        {
            //Your code here
        }));

        base.Initialize();
    }
}
```